# Skype Meeting plugin not loading in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook I have the Skype For Business plugin:

[image]

A few days ago it stopped showing up. I went to COM Add-ins and saw it is unchecked so I checked it and restarted Outlook. But the button was still missing and it was unchecked again in COM Addins:

[image]

Why is it refusing to load?

Answer (score 2):

After some trying, what worked for me was closing Outlook, opening it with Run As Administrator, then removing the addin and adding it again. The plugin DLL was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\UCAddin.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps to check the registry:
You can visit: https://www.finetechweb.com/post/skype-meeting-button-always-gets-disabled-after-restarting-outlook  **for detailed information:**

1. Exit Outlook if it is running.
2. Press the Windows function key, search for "regedit," and then click OK.
3. In Registry Editor, locate the following subkey:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\UcAddin.LyncAddin.1
4. In the details pane, double-click LoadBehavior. If the value in the Value data box is not 3, change it to 3 and then click OK.
5. Exit Registry Editor.
6. Start Outlook.